# Bundler wants to re-install rails engine as gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, rails-engines

I have a Rails 4.1 project, running under RVM, that depends on a Rails Engine.

In the Gemfile of the main app, I reference the engine:

gem 'garage', path: '/srv/webapps/garage'

The engine is deployed to that directory, not as a packaged .gem file, but with all the files unpacked - it contains, at the top level, its own Gemfile, garage.gemspec, and the directories app lib spec ...

When running "bundle" in the parent app, it aborts with this message:

Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - garage-0.0.6.gem
An error occurred while installing garage (0.0.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install garage -v '0.0.6'` succeeds before bundling.

(That version number matches the version number claimed by the 'garage' engine).

Yet the app runs just fine - it finds that gem (in the path pointed to by the Gemfile).

So, why is Bundler trying to make another copy of a gem already installed locally?  And, on what path is it getting "permission denied" - which is a puzzle as I am the owner of every file on both the main app and the engine's deployment directories, and have write access to /usr/local/rvm as well.

Comment: Please post the _full_ output of the command you ran.

Comment: Heisenbug? The problem has not recurred, but I've only deployed this app once since originally posting.  I'll return here with more detail if it happens again.

Comment: Have a look at this gem, it helps when working with gems from local sources: https://github.com/EPI-USE-Labs/git-bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found and fixed the error today (this app is only deployed once a month or so).

When a Bundler app points to a local gem from its own Gemfile:

```
# main_app/Gemfile:
gem 'my_gem', path: '/srv/webapps/my_gem'
```

...then for main_app's Bundle to be successful, the top level directory of my_gem *MUST* be writable by the current user.

Even though it doesn't seem to make lasting changes to my_gem's directory, evidently some sort of temporary file is created and then destroyed in the top level of my_gem. (Probably my_gem-0.0.6.gem, as indicated by the error message - which unfortunately does not include the complete path, as that's what made all the difference!)

```
$ chmod -R a-w /srv/webapps/my_gem

$ cd /srv/webapps/main_app

$ bundle
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - my_gem-0.0.6.gem

# making the gem's Gemfile writable has no effect
$ chmod a+w /srv/webapps/my_gem/Gemfile*
$ bundle
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - my_gem-0.0.6.gem

# but making the top level directory writable does work:
$ chmod a+w /srv/webapps/my_gem
$ bundle
Using my_gem 0.0.6 from source at /srv/webapps/my_gem
Your bundle is complete!
```